# checking tha data already exists in the table

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a table named `brand`,fields are:

- `BrandId`
- `BrandName`.

Then I have a form for adding brand. If we add a brand name (eg:*Acer*).then if we add the same brand again there will check is already exist that name in the table. How can i check it in asp.net?

Comment: Table name meann database table? if it is which `db` you are using?

Comment: How do you connect to SQL server ? Query or Entity Framework ?

Comment: Which database? And also, if the BrandName should be unique then this requirement should be on the database table setting the unique index to true whatever database you are using

Answer (score 2):

`If` you want to insert new record than use

```
if exists(select brandName from [brand] where brandName <> @pbrandName) 
-- insert statement
```

`Else if` you want to update the existing record than you can use.. (by using existing record id)

```
if exists(select brandName from [brand] where BrandId <> @pBrandId and brandName <> @pbrandName) 
-- update statement
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql server

```
declare @Exist INT=0
    Select @Exist= COUNT(BrandName)
    From TableName
    Where BrandId= IdValue
    Group By(BrandName)  
 IF(@Exist=0)
   BEGIN
     --Insert
   END
```